# Binding handlers to events of dynamically added ActiveX controls

Tags: jquery, event-handling, activex

An ActiveX control is being loaded conditionally based on browser and other factors.

In order to handle events from the ActiveX control, a simple jquery `.bind('Event', ...)` won't work.  Instead, it seems to me that my only choice is to use `<script ... for='myPlugin' event='Event'></script>` style binding.

1) It seems that if the script tag statically part of the HTML and is loaded before the control exists on the page, then IE won't fire the event
2) Hard-coding the object IDs is unacceptable if there needed to be (dynamically) multiple instances of the plugin

But when I add the following code, I get "'param1' is undefined" immediately, before the event should fire (I'm almost certain that it is not in response to the event firing).

```
$('HEAD').append($('<script language="javascript" ' +
    'type="text/javascript" for="myPlugin" event="Event(param1)">' + 
    '$('#myPlugin').triggerHandler("jQueryBoundEvent", [ param1 ]);' +
'<' + '/script>'));
```

From the web, I've gathered that jQuery interfere's with adding script tags and rather eval()s them.  That would explain the unbound param1 and the immediate execution of the script.  The script's for and event attributes are lost during the eval().

Is there another approach to load the plugin dynamically, and attach to it's events without hardcoding the handlers?

=======

Alternatively, it seems from various posts that even though $.bind() doesn't work for ActiveX and XPI plugins, that attachEvent() or addEventListener() should work.  Is this the case?  I haven't been able to confirm it for a dynamically added plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `appendTo('head')` instead of `$('head').append(...`

I know JQuery say they're basically identical except for the order, but IE disagrees and prefers `appendTo()` when injecting scripts into the head.

Try this:

```
var plugin_html = '$("#myPlugin").triggerHandler("jQueryBoundEvent", [ param1 ]);';
$('<script />').attr(
{
    type: 'text/javascript',
    for: 'myPlugin',
    event: 'Event(param1)'
}).html(plugin_html).appendTo($('head'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried both `$('<script ...').appendTo('HEAD');` and `$('<script ...').appendTo($('HEAD'));` with no change in behavior.  Am I getting you right?

Comment: I'm still working through it.  'for' must/ought to be in quotes as a keyword.  But the bigger issue is that .html() doesn't seem to work for script tags.  I get "Unexpected call to method or property access."

Comment: Also, if I take out the part that sets the code of the script, .html(...), it doesn't generate any errors.  I would still expect to see the empty script tag with attributes in the IE Developer Tools Html tab (especially after "refresh" in that tool) having been added to the HEAD tag, but I'm not seeing that.  Even if I resolve the .html() issue, I think that problem would remain.  Is your sample code working in your environment?

Comment: Thanks for your original effort here.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle which recreates your error? I'll play around on it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: no, can jsfiddle do ActiveX?  But no matter.  attachEvent and addEventListener work - but the events must be generated.  This ActiveX control is poorly documented - it only generates these events in certain "modes" - modes which I wasn't in at the time.  Thanks!